# I don't know how to solve this slim error

Tags: php, slim

I'm new with slim and php. Currently doing a website for college with those technologies and angular.

I have a table in phpmyadmin with some data I want to show in my website and I'm having some problems with slim I don't understand.

This is the error I have. We are using postman to test our php code.

```
 <h1>Slim Application Error</h1>
        <p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p>
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <div>
            <strong>Type:</strong> RuntimeException
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>Message:</strong> Callable Project\Mapas\MapasControllergetMapas does not exist
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>File:</strong> /Users/raul/Desktop/Proyecto Web/pruebaPhp/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
        </div>
```

this is my 'Mapas.php'

```
{
    public $id;
    public $nombre;
    public $descripcion;
    public $imagen;
    public function __construct($id, $nombre, $descripcion, $imagen)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
    }


}
```

this is my 'MapasController.php'

```
class MapasController
{

    private $dao;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->dao = new MapasDao($container['projectDao']);

    }


    function getMapas(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
    {
        $mapas = $this->dao->getMapas();
        return $response->withJson($mapas);
    }

}
```

this is my 'MapasDao.php'

```
class MapasDao
{
    private $dbConnection;
    public function __construct(ProjectDao $dbConnection)
    {
        $this->dbConnection = $dbConnection;
    }

    public function getMapas()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mapas";
        return $this->dbConnection->fetchAll($sql);
    }
}
```

and this is the route I'm calling

```
$app->get('/mapas', MapasController::class. 'getMapas');
```

I don't know why the petition get is not reading 'getMapas' in 'MapasController' when it should be.

Also in the url postman is showing('Project\Mapas\MapasControllergetMapas') I don't understand why there is no backslash or anything between 'MapasController', which is my php file and 'getMapas' which is a function inside the file.

Comment: I think you want `$app->get('/mapas', MapasController::class. ':getMapas');`

Comment: you are right, thank you so much.